# Reset state after unmount screen - Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After getting data from API I set it to state, and render items in Flatlist,

when I select any item from it I manipulate data and add a new property to item object named as "toggle: true"

and it's works well when I select any item from list I add a border based on `toggle`,
But when I go back to previous screen then re open the lists screen I can see the border rendered around the items, although I reset the state when the unmounted screen

So what's the wrong I made here?

Code snippet

Data

```
export default {
  ...
  services: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'nameS0',
      logo:
        'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hotel-98/64/hair-dryer-tools-beauty-hairdressing-512.png',
      price: 19.99,
    },
  
  ],
  employees: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'name0',
      img:
        'https://www.visualelementmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/person-4-400x629.jpg',
    },
    ...
  ],
};




const VendorProfile = ({navigation}) => {
  const [services, setServices] = React.useState(null);
  const [employees, setEmployees] = React.useState(null);
  const [serviceSelected, setServiceSelected] = React.useState(null);
  const [employeeSelected, setEmployeeSelected] = React.useState(null);
  

  // For selected Item (services, employees)
  const itemSelected = (data, id) => {
    const updated = data.map((item) => {
      item.toggle = false;
      if (item.id === id) {
        item.toggle = true;
        data === services
          ? setServiceSelected(item)
          : setEmployeeSelected(item);
      }
      return item;
    });
    data === services ? setServices(updated) : setEmployees(updated);
  };

  ...

  const renderEmployees = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => itemSelected(employees, item.id)}
        delayPressIn={0}
        style={styles.employeeContainer}>
        <EmployeePattern style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} />
        <View style={styles.employeeLogo}>
          <Image
            source={{uri: item.img}}
            style={[styles.imgStyle, {borderRadius: 25}]}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop: 30}}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}> {item.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
          {item.toggle && <AntDesign name="check" size={25} color="#000" />} // here it's stuck after back and reopen the screen
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };



  React.useEffect(() => {
    setServices(VendorProfileData.services);
    setEmployees(VendorProfileData.employees);
    () => {
      setServices(null);
      setEmployees(null);
    };
  }, []);


 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

 <FlatList
            data={services}
            renderItem={renderServices}
            horizontal
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}
          />

.....

</View>
);

};
```

Comment: so you don't want to reset your state ?

Comment: The main issue i guess in `itemSelected` function I add new property to the item object, and set the new state to it as you see in the last line in that function, 
But When I log the `Mock Data` when cleaning up the effect it's appear the new prop 'toggle' in every item in an array, That's mean it's manipulated the `Mock Data` itself,
So what I Want "not manipulate the Mock Data, And just manipulate the local state" So that's why i need to reset state when unmounting  I hope you understand the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after trying multiple times, i got it

change this

```
 const updated = data.map((item) => {
```

to this

```
 const updated = data.map((old) => {
      let item = {...old};
```

and please make sure everything is working and we didn't break a thing :),

On your ItemSelected function you are passing the whole employees list, and going through it now thats fine, but when you changing one item inside this list without "recreating it" the reference to that item is still the same "because its an object" meaning that we are modifying the original item, and since we are doing so, the item keeps its old reference, best way to avoid that is to recreate the object,
hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Is VendorProfileData.employees an array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array.

Comment: Hmm, When i log `console.log('VendorProfileData.employees', VendorProfileData.employees);` when Cleaning up an effect
I can see toggle property, So that's mean it's changing the reference? Or shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343728/reset-state-after-unmount-screen-hooks#comment112009732_63343728) comment I wrote to understand what I mean

Comment: Can you upload the code somewhere? i want to.try few things

Comment: Check [here](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/test-vp)

Comment: thats my last change, if it breaks something else, im out, :P

Comment: haha no, you're right, it works properly, Can you please explain it in the answer that's help, other users, what's wrong on it :)